# Why isn't this bottom text touching the bottom of the image?

Tags: terminal, command-line, imagemagick

The following bash script uses [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) to create an image with white text and black background:

```
#!/bin/bash

font_path="/home/alex/.local/share/fonts/Unknown Vendor/TrueType/skullsandcrossbones/skullsandcrossbones_Medium.ttf"

magick -size 4500x5400 xc:black -gravity north \
  -font "$font_path" -pointsize 436 -fill white -annotate +0+0 'HELLO WORLD' \
  -gravity south -annotate +0+0 'BOTTOM TEXT' \
  -type truecolor -colorspace rgb "bottom.png"
```

[image]

The `-gravity north` flag makes the top text to touch the top edge of the image. But the `-gravity south` flag doesn't make the bottom text to touch the bottom edge of the image.

What could be the reason?

Note: I checked the font with no line height in a vector editor. There doesn't seem to be any space under the font:

[image]

Update: I realized that if I decrease the font size to 26, it almost touches the bottom edge of the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the upper case "R" in your top line, it looks like the descenders on that font drop quite far below the baseline. You could adjust the geometry of the "-annotate" operation to accommodate that, but I would probably make each text unit as a "label:" and composite them onto the background.

```
magick -font ubuntu -pointsize 436 -fill white -background none \
   label:'HELLO WORLD' label:'BOTTOM TEXT' -trim \
   -write mpr:texts -delete 0--1 \
   -size 4500x5400 xc:black \
   mpr:texts[0] -gravity north -geometry +0+20 -composite \
   mpr:texts[1] -gravity south -geometry +0+20 -composite \
   -type truecolor -colorspace rgb "bottom.png"
```

That starts by setting  the fill color, background color, pointsize, and font. Then it creates the top and bottom label, does a "-trim" operation to get rid of that excess space below the text, and writes those labels to IM's internal memory register "mpr:texts".

Then it creates the black canvas. Make sure  you've created the labels before setting the size on the canvas, or IM will try to make your labels fit the canvas size rather than the pointsize.

After creating the black canvas, it reads in the top label "mpr:texts[0]", sets the gravity and geometry, and composites that label at the top. Then it reads in bottom label "mpr:texts[1]", sets the geometry and gravity for its position on the canvas, and composites that, too. The result is the image in your example except the location of the labels is dictated by geometry without regard to the top and bottom spacing in the original font.

I have not tested this command on a *nix OS. It may require escaping some special characters, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. What's the difference between using annotate and a label in this case?

Comment: The "-annotate" operation applies the text directly to an image. A "label:" is created as a separate image on its own background, in this case transparent. You can use "-trim" to remove all excess background from a "label:", then composite it onto the image in your specified location.

Answer (score 1):

Your command works fine for me on IM 7.1.1.7 Mac OSX Monterey using the Ubuntu font.  What font are you using? Perhaps its font glyphs are in error.

```
magick -size 4500x5400 xc:black -gravity north \
-font ubuntu -pointsize 436 -fill white -annotate +0+0 'HELLO WORLD' \
-gravity south -annotate +0+0 'BOTTOM TEXT' \
-type truecolor -colorspace rgb "bottom.png"
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's strange. The font is called Skulls and Crossbones. I downloaded it from here: https://www.fontspace.com/category/pirates. Thanks for trying my script. I'll check other fonds.

Answer (score 1):

If I render your image with your font in Imagemagick 7.1.1.7, I get

```
magick -size 4500x5400 xc:black \
-font /Users/fred/library/fonts/Skullsandcrossbones-RppKM.ttf \
-pointsize 436 -fill white \
-gravity north -annotate +0+0 'HELLO WORLD' \
-gravity south -annotate +0+0 'BOTTOM TEXT' \
-type truecolor -colorspace rgb "bottom.png"
```

[image]

Using Imagemagick on your "BOTTOM TEXT", to get the glyph information, we see it has a descender of 222 pixels, even though there is no character in the BOTTOM TEXT with a descender.  The distance from the bottom of the text to the bottom of the image was about that much. So I think your font glyph is not programmed correctly.

```
magick -debug annotate  xc: -font /Users/fred/library/fonts/Skullsandcrossbones-RppKM.ttf -pointsize 436 \
-annotate 0 'BOTTOM TEXT' null: 2>&1 |\
grep Metrics: | fmt -w80
  Metrics: text: BOTTOM TEXT; width: 3338; height: 639; ascent: 379; descent:
  -222; max advance: 718; bounds: 0,-13  389.125,325.969; origin: 3338,0; pixels
  per em: 436,436; underline position: -65.4; underline thickness: 21.8
```

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#font_info